# .NET async - when do I need to care that the same synchronizationcontext is used after await?

Tags: .net, async-await, synchronizationcontext

So, if I await a function, I have some choices:

```
var retVal = await someAwaitableFunction();
continuation code...
```

or

```
var retVal = await someAwaitableFunction().ConfigureAwait(false);
continuation code...
```

The latter, as I understand it is saying "eh, I don't really need you to re-enter with the same synchronizationContext when the continuation occurs". The former ensures it.

That's fine - just that it seems to me the cases you want to reuse the synch context are few. Seems to only be WPF - where you want to guarantee the UI thread/context is the one that continues you so you can muck around with UI elements.

Are there other situations? I haven't really seen any in examples, and the one that is discussed all the time is... the UI thread situation, which I am aware of.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't try to mess with async unless you really know what you are doing. All the synchronization context stuff has a lot of gotchas that are hard to find out and hard to debug if you have troubles with it.

So even though it's not a direct answer to the question, I suggest that you do not use all the advanced features unless you really need them and you have to have a good reason for that as well. So you just use ordinary awaits and 99% all shall be fine, and the performance is good enough anyway unless you are doing some real core functionality that has to be extremely fast.

Comment: Well, yeah, thanks for that - but what I'm trying to do is understand it properly. :)

Comment: Then it's not too much help, sorry :)